# Azure and Azure stack python SDK

Tags: python, azure

Can I use same python SDK for Azure cloud as well as Azure stack? It would help if you can point me to some documentation which talks about what SDK can be used for Azure and Azure stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management).And you can get all azure python sdk at [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk).

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For most the libraries, yes, you can use same python SDK for Azure cloud as well as Azure stack.

The tricky part is if you don't have the latest service API installed on your Azure stack, you may need to specify the `api-version` when using the libraries to make them work.

Please share the libraries you want to use or open issues on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python if they don't work for you.

(I work in Azure SDK team)